# Customized class options doesn't work

Tags: document-classes, class-options

I'm trying to declare a new option `poly` in my `.cls` file.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{classname}
\ClassInfo{JH}{Copyright (c), 2022.}
%
\DeclareOption{poly}{%
\PassOptionsToClass{french,a4paper,twocolumn,DIV=45,twoside=false,numbers=enddot,parskip=half,headinclude=true,footinclude=true,chapterprefix=true,listof=totoc,toc=indentunnumbered}{scrbook}
}
%
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
```

In the main `.tex` file, I have :

```
\documentclass[poly]{classname}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

But not all options are taken into account : for example, `DIV=45` option is OK but `landscape` is not. How can I fix this ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, for me `DIV=45` is picked up.

Comment: Sorry, I exchanged my two examples : the `landscape` option is not picked up.

Comment: Those options are not picked up because they are no options supported by `scrbook`. Instead those options should've been passed on to `typearea` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the comments, I have changed the initial `cls` file like this.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{classname}
\ClassInfo{JH}{Copyright (c), 2022.}
%
\DeclareOption{poly}{%
\PassOptionsToClass{french,twocolumn,numbers=enddot, parskip=half,chapterprefix=true,listof=totoc,toc=indentunnumbered}{scrbook}%
\PassOptionsToPackage{DIV=45,
                     landscape,
                     a4paper,
                     headinclude=true,
                     footinclude=true,
                     twoside=false,
                     }{typearea}%
    }%
%
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
```